# Difference between LinkExtractor and SgmlLinkExtractor

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy framework and I've seen some tutorial using `LinkExtractors` and a few using `SgmlLinkExtractor`. I've tried searching for the differences/pros-cons for both, but the results haven't been satisfying.

Can someone tell me the difference between both? When should we use the above extractors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem why you cannot find the references to what `SgmlLinkExtractor` is, is that it is now *deprecated* (related [changeset](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/756)). You can find the `SgmlLinkExtractor` definition [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/link-extractors.html?highlight=sgmllinkextractor#module-scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml) - inside the Scrapy 0.24 docs.

And, you should not be using `SgmlLinkExtractor` anymore - Scrapy now leaves a single link extractor only - the [`LxmlLinkExtractor`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml) - the one to which the `LinkExtractor` alias points to.

Comment: As for the differences, `SgmlLinkExtractor` is based on [`sgmllib.SGMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sgmllib.html) (`sgml` module is deprecated since Python 2.6, and is not available in Python3), whereas the default `LinkExtractor` is implemented on top of `lxml`, which is somewhat faster and well maintained.