# How to use sitemap of urls in scrapy spider?

Tags: xml, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping, sitemap

I want to create a spider which scrapes urls based on `sitemap.xml` of the webpage. So I don't have `start_urls`. I want to determine which urls to scrape using `sitemap.xml`.

I thought about adding a method `_parse_sitemap` and parse it using `requests` and `lxml` but it can be an overkill.

Is there some built-in method to get all urls inside `<loc>` tags?

What I have done so far:

Spider gets one url and `meta = {'sitemap':True}` so parse method knows that it has to call `_parse_sitemap` which `yield`s `Request` objects based on urls from sitemap.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request


class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    sitemap = 'www.example.com/sitemap.xml'
    start_urls = [sitemap]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url=self.sitemap,meta={'sitemap':True})

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.meta.get('sitemap'):
            self._parse_sitemap(response)
        else:
            # parse normal url

    def _parse_sitemap(self, response):
        # how to get urls?
        urls = []
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)
```

It's just one `xml` so I think I shouldn't use `SitemapSpider`. What do you recommend? As you can see I don't know how to parse `urls` inside `_parse_sitemap` spider.

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't use SitemapSpider because you only have one file? Your spider could be very simple, just like the first example from the docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#sitemapspider-examples

Comment: You can simply use SgmlLinkExtractor.It will give all the links from the page.
Use below Imports

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

Add below line in class and specify you function in callback, it will responce all urls 

rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=False), )

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use SgmlLinkExtractor. It will give all the links from the page.

Use below Imports

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
```

Add below line in class and specify you function in callback, it will responce all urls

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='_parse_sitemap', follow=False), )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `SgmlLinkExtractor` is now deprecated, `LxmlLinkExtractor` should be used. More information about the difference between them is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283564/difference-between-linkextractor-and-sgmllinkextractor).